# Generating a valid EPUB3 Navigation Document from XML via XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, epub3

I'm trying to generate an EPUB3 Navigation Document through XSLT from an XML file.

Sample XML:

```
<div class="toc" id="s1">
    <p class="toc-title">Detailed Contents</p>
    <ul class="toc">
        <li class="toc-item">
            <a class="ref-chap" id="a1" href="#a1">Preface</a>
        </li>
        <li class="book-section">
            <a class="ref-chap" id="a2" href="#a2">
                <b>Part I.</b>
            </a>
            <ul class="book-section">
                <li class="toc-item">
                    <a class="ref-chap" id="a3" href="#a3">
                        <b>Chapter 1</b>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="chapter-section">
                        <li class="toc-item">
                            <a class="ref-chap" id="a4" href="#a4">
                                <b>Sub Chapter a</b>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="chapter-subsection">
                                <li class="toc-item">
                                    <a class="ref-chap" id="a5" href="#a5">Sub Chapter B</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="book-section">
                <li class="toc-item">
                    <a class="ref-chap" id="a6" href="#a6">
                        <b>Chapter 2</b>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="chapter-section">
                        <li class="toc-item">
                            <a class="ref-chap" id="a7" href="#a7">
                                <b>Sub Chapter A</b>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Needed output:

```
<nav xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops" epub:type="toc" id="toc">
    <h1>Detailed Contents</h1>
    <ol>
        <li><a href="a1">Preface: To Our Readers</a></li>
        <li><a href="a2"><b>Part I</b></a>
            <ol>
                <li><a href="a3"><b>Chapter 1</b></a>
                    <ol>
                        <li><a href="a4"><b>Sub Chapter A</b></a>
                            <ol>
                                <li><a href="a5">Sub Chapter B</a></li>
                            </ol>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
                <li><a href="a6"><b>Chapter 2</b></a>
                    <ol>
                        <li><a href="a7"><b>Sub Chapter A</b></a></li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
</nav>
```

My problem area is the `<ol>` child of Part I, I need it to close AFTER Chapter 2, but it is closing after the end of Chapter 1 instead with the following XSLT.

My XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs epub"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="xhtml" include-content-type="no" xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="div[@class='toc']">
        <xsl:element name="nav">
            <xsl:attribute name="epub:type" select="'toc'"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="id" select="'toc'"/>
            <xsl:element name="h1">
                <xsl:value-of select="//div[@class='toc']/p[@class='toc-title']"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="div[@class='toc']//ul[@class='toc'] | div[@class='toc']//ul[@class='book-section'] | div[@class='toc']//ul[@class='chapter-section' or @class='chapter-subsection']">
        <xsl:element name="ol">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="div[@class='toc']//li[@class='toc-item']">
        <xsl:element name="li">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="div[@class='toc']//li[@class='book-section']">
        <xsl:element name="li">
            <xsl:apply-templates xml:space="default"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a[@class='ref-chap']">
        <xsl:element name="a">
            <xsl:attribute name="href" select="concat(substring-after(@href, '#'),'.xhtml')"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template priority="1" match="ul[@class='chapter-section' or @class='chapter-subsection']//a[@class='ref-chap']">
        <xsl:variable name="pagenumber" select="following-sibling::a[@class='page-ref']"/>
        <xsl:element name="a">
            <xsl:attribute name="href" select="concat(substring-after(ancestor::ul[@class='chapter-section'][1]/preceding-sibling::a[@class='ref-chap'][1]/@href, '#'),'.xhtml','#page',$pagenumber)"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Gives me a nonvalid EPUB3 nav doc:

```
<nav xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops" epub:type="toc" id="toc">
   <h1>Detailed Contents</h1>Detailed Contents
   <ol>
      <li>
         <a href="a1.xhtml">Preface</a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="a2.xhtml">Part I.</a>
         <ol>
            <li>
               <a href="a3.xhtml">Chapter 1</a>
               <ol>
                  <li>
                     <a href="a3.xhtml#page">Sub Chapter a</a>
                     <ol>
                        <li>
                           <a href="a3.xhtml#page">Sub Chapter B</a>
                        </li>
                     </ol>
                  </li>
               </ol>
            </li>
         **</ol>
         <ol>**
            <li>
               <a href="a6.xhtml">Chapter 2</a>
               <ol>
                  <li>
                     <a href="a6.xhtml#page">Sub Chapter A</a>
                  </li>
               </ol>
            </li>
         </ol>
      </li>
   </ol>
</nav>
```

Emphasis ** was added to indicate these tags are where the problem is. They should not be in the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is group together the **ul[@class='book-section']**.

There are different ways to do that, one would be to use for-each-group in the parent template of li[@class='book-section'] so you could change that template to:

```
<xsl:template match="div[@class='toc']//li[@class='book-section']">
    <xsl:element name="li">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="xhtml:a[@class='ref-chap']"/>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="ul[@class='book-section']" group-by="@class">
            <ol>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/node()"/>
            </ol>
        </xsl:for-each-group> 
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Another way would be to only match the first of the ul[@class='book-section'] but then apply this to the children of the following, too, like this:

```
<xsl:template match="div[@class='toc']//ul[@class='book-section'][1]">
    <xsl:element name="ol">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="* | following-sibling::ul[@class='book-section']/*"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Awesome. The first suggestion works great. I had to add <xsl:apply-templates select="a[@class='ref-chap']"/> after the <xsl:element name="li"> so that the anchor and text and output as well.